# Perform regex search on a previously regex-matched line (one-liner)

Tags: sed, awk, regular-expression, perl

I need to print a string which is in a unique line in a long text file. Example relevant line in file `long.txt`:

`Software version 4.0.10, 2002-03-28`

The wanted string is exactly `4.0.10`.

The steps probably are:

- Match the line; e.g. with a regexp such as `/^Software/`
- Once the line has been found, perform a search on it for the wanted string (another regexp)
- Print the string

How can I accomplish this in one line (no pipes pls) with tools such as `sed`, `awk` or `perl`?

Note: The actual regex isn't so relevant. What matters most is the commands and syntax involved. Thanks!

Comment: The trick about translating such a description into working code is that we must inevitably make assumptions about your input.  Does the desired number always occur just before a comma (as I have assumed)?  Does it always occur after exactly two whitespace-separated words, and end in a comma followed by whitespace (as Jay has assumed)?

Comment: Yes, I understand. But actually the important part here is not so much a singular regexp but how apply a command to a previous command output. IMO the answers, yours in particular, are very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options for you

```
sed -n 's/Software version \([^,]\+\).*/\1/p' file
```

```
awk -F '[ ,]' '$1=="Software" && $2=="version" {print $3}' file
```

```
perl -nE '/Software version (.+?),/ and say $1' file
```

```
grep -oP '(?<=Software version ).+?(?=,)' file
```

All assume there are no commas in the version string.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite general; I want to take a moment to discuss the design of `sed` and how it works to handle such use cases.

`sed` is the stream editor.  It accepts text input in a stream—whether from a pipe, from a single file, or from a sequence of files one after the other—performs actions on that text stream, and outputs text.  (Note that it is *not* intended or designed for file editing in its original conception, though it is often pressed into service for that purpose.)

The keynotes of `sed`'s operation that you should understand, are:

- `sed` deals with text line by line.  The command(s) you give is essentially a loop that operates on every line of input (by default), and prints the result at the end (by default).
- A command in `sed` consists of an optional conditional test (or "pattern") and an action to be performed.
- All the actions are a single character command, e.g. `p`rint, `s`ubstitute, `d`elete
- The most common condition is a regex to be matched against the line, but line numbers can be used as well.
- A *range* can be specified, meaning: Do the following action for all lines *from* (first condition) *up to* (second condition).

There is [a very thorough tutorial and reference on `sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) available free online, which I recommend reading in full.

For your scenario, the command you want is something like:

```
sed -n -e '/^Software/{s/,.*//;s/.*[[:space:]]//;p;}' filename
```

Which translates to:

- `-n`: suppress `sed`'s default action of printing each line of input
- `-e`: Execute following `sed` command
- `/^Software/`: Perform the following set of commands contained in `{}`, only on lines which match this regex
- `s/,.*//`: Remove the first comma from the line (and everything after it)
- `s/.*[[:space:]]//`: Remove everything up to the last whitespace character in the line
- `p`: Print the resulting text.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what `sed` is about. I see several details such as using `;` to separate between commands.

Answer (score 1):

Give this tested version a try:

```
 awk '{if ($0 ~ /^Software/) {print substr($3,1,length($3)-1)}}' long.txt
```

It prints the 3rd element of each line starting with **Software**.

**substr** is used to removed the last char '**,**' from the 3rd element.

The test:

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /^Software/) {print substr($3,1,length($3)-1)}}' long.txt
4.0.10
```

Comment: Or just `awk '/^Software/ {print substr($3,1,length($3)-1)}' long.txt`.  You don't need the `if` construct very often in `awk`, and essentially never for simple one-liners; `awk` has the same "condition -> action" syntax design as `sed`.

Comment: I tried first but it is generating a syntax error with **awk** installed on the linux debian I use for the tests.

Comment: Maybe someone could explain me why my awk cannot use the syntax described in the Bruce Bernett's tutorial? FIRST awk is a symbolic links to mawk.    
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 ||| squeeze 6.0.10 ||| gawk (1:3.1.7.dfsg-5), mawk (1.3.3-15), original-awk (2010-05-23-1)

Comment: @Jay You can use `sudo update-alternatives --config awk` to change the `/usr/bin/awk` symlink between awk versions.

Comment: @undostres it wrote an error like no other alternatives.... Thx anyway.